# How to insert multiple records with OrientJS?

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I just started with OrientJS and OrientDB and I try to insert multiple records at the same time.

If I use this code nothing happens, no error, but no insertion either, what do i do wrong?

```
testRecords.map(el =>
    db
      .insert()
      .into('Profile')
      .set({
        email: el.email,
        password: el.password,
        verifyEmailToken: el.verifyEmailToken,
        changePasswordToken: el.changePasswordToken,
      })
      .one());
```

If I use the OrientDB SQL and the db.query then it works fine with this code below (but with this it looks kinda strange how I have to setup the values, one example value from the value array looks like this example `'("testemail@test.com", "123", "123456789", "123456789")'`

```
const OSQL = `INSERT INTO ${className} (${properties}) VALUES ${testValues}`;
console.log(OSQL);

db.query(OSQL);
```

Can somebody guide me how to use properly the OrientJS API?

Comment: Do you have a failing script.
I've done this and it works fine
https://gist.github.com/maggiolo00/d1d628519a9e550760002a13af8137b2

Comment: Thanks for the gist @wolf4ood. I found that may be JEST test runner is causing the problem for me. Can you check this for me [https://gist.github.com/maggiolo00/d1d628519a9e550760002a13af8137b2#gistcomment-2224659](comment and question to your gist)

Comment: Hi Peter let me check

Comment: @wolf4ood  I figured out :) Jest is expecting a promise back, so createTestRecord has to be a function which returns a promise then it works :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey guys, gist links are not working, would you mind updating ?